# How to set the option Header and Content in HTTP POST Resquest in Android

Tags: android, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I used HttpPost and HttpURLConnection in Android to send the request with following Headers and Contents:

Headers:
api_key: 9a8akx8badkaxxxx,
speed: 0,
voice: male,
prosody: 1,
Cache-Control: no-cache

Contents (with Content-Type: text/plain):
Hello everyone

These are my code:
*Using the HttpPost:

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(requestURL);
        post.addHeader("api_key", "9a8akx8badkaxxxx");
        post.addHeader("speed", "0");
        post.addHeader("voice", "male");
        post.addHeader("prosody", "1");
        post.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[body]", "Hello everyone"));
        AbstractHttpEntity ent= null;

        ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);

        ent.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        ent.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        post.setEntity(ent);
        post.setURI(new URI("http://api.openfpt.vn/text2speech/v4"));
        HttpResponse response =client.execute(post);
```

*Using the HttpURLConnection:

```
    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("api_key", "9a8akx8badkaxxxx");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    conn.setRequestProperty("speed", "0");
    conn.setRequestProperty("voice", "male");
    conn.setRequestProperty("prosody", "1");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

and then I don't know the method to put the content "Hello everyone" into HttpURLConnection

The result always error. But when I use the add-on HttpRequester in Firefox, the response is OK.
please help me to create and set Http Request in Android

Comment: Can you post your code, so we can see how you set your headers and content?
In general I use: httppost.setHeader("String", "String"+whateverNeeded);
to set the headers.

Comment: I just post my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to set the content-type:

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(builder.getUrl());
        httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

To set arbitrary headers, I believe it should be done like this:

```
        httppost.setHeader("api_key", "9a8akx8badkaxxxx");
        httppost.setHeader("speed", "0");
        httppost.setHeader("voice", "male");
        httppost.setHeader("voice", "male");
        httppost.setHeader("prosody", "1");
        httppost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

To send the data, choose a name for your post field (here Fn and IdDevice):

```
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
        // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Fn",function));
        // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IdDevice",IdDevice));
```

**EDIT START**

```
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content","Hello everyone"));
```

**EDIT END**

```
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

And finally, execute the post request:

```
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: But you miss the "Contents (with Content-Type: text/plain): Hello everyone". I don't know how to add the content to httppost

Comment: You want to post some data to your server, is this correct? When you do so, the data you send is always inside some field, like in a form or something. Using php in your server (just as an example) you will check for the variable $_POST['something_in_here'] and that variable has the post content. In the example I gave you, we are sending 2 fields (Fn and IdDevice) as if they were posted by a form, so you can get them on the server accessing $_POST['Fn'] and $_POST['IdDevice']. Hope it helps.

Comment: I´ll update the answer using variable "Content" with the value "Hello everyone". If it helps, please accept the answer.

Comment: It's not work :(  I declare HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); - Is it ok?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Post the stack here

Comment: I put code in try-catch and result in logcat: "E/HTTP: Error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: Ok it work!!! I just add the code HttpPost into class extends AsyncTask. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Yes, you cannot send network requests on the ui thread, cause it will lock the ui. Glad it helped.